# Google Tag Manager jQuery overwriting site jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I have a site that is using jQuery 1.11.0 as it needs to still support ie8 (I know it's ridiculous, but the client wants it as they are dinosaurs and still use it throughout their company), but I have a bug where none of my functions were working after a particular point and after a lot of debugging, I have tracked it down to google tag manager downloading the jquery 2.1.5 library.

This is conflicting with my current library and removing all the functions from the `jQuery.fn.` and causing my site to crash.

I've read that gtm will download jquery if it can't find a library or deems the old library too old.  Does anyone know how to stop this conflict or stop gtm downloading the jquery file?

My current call to tag manager is like this:

```js
//Google tag manager
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'XXX-XXXXXX');
```

Is there anything I can add to this or change it?

I should also say that I am unable to use `noConflict` and changing the jQuery var name for the current code as it is using a cms there are some scripts I am unable to change

Comment: No idea if there's an easier way, but you could use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to store a new reference to your version of jQuery 1.11.0, then modify your own code to use that. If you're using plug-ins you haven't written yourself that might still cause issues.

Comment: Are you sure GTM downloads jQuery? As far as I am aware of, GTM doesn't rely on jQuery.

Comment: @nyuen yep, definately sure it's tag manager - if I remove the code, the site works perfectly.  Add it again and it breaks everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out GTM doesn't actually download jQuery as I was lead to believe in other posts on the subject.  Instead, you can write bespoke code for GTM to track certain things; and as such the marketing company that manages the account had written some form abandonment tracking code that caused the GTM script to download the extra jQuery library.

So if like me you don't touch that side of the GTM, the first thing you need to look at if you have the same issue, is your marketing company's bespoke code!